# how to pass query string parameter

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I am building dynamic html with contents coming from sharepoint list

```
   innerHtml += " <a href='Mypage.aspx?AgeOfPerson='" + Age + "'" + ">";
```

But i dont get parameter i passed of Age. I get blank. While i debug i can see i get value in Age variable but after rendering i blank parameter. So i just get this

```
http://mysite/Mypage.aspx?AgeOfPerson=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
innerHtml += " <a href='Mypage.aspx?AgeOfPerson=" + Age + "'>";
```

Remove `'` from after the `=` sign. If it doesn't work then paste your full code.

Comment: Happy to hear from you that it helped..!! :-)

Comment: Please don't forget to mark as answer if it helped you... @Happy